# Doubt about an operation involving vectors

Tags: vectors

Given $\vec{u}=(1;2;-1)$ and $\vec{a}=(1;-3;4)$, calculate $\vec{u}-\frac{3}{\vec{u}} . \vec{a}$.

Well, I think that the operation $\frac{3}{\vec{u}}$ is not defined, is it? In case it's possible, what should I do?

Comment: You are correct that must be a typo. Perhaps the expression was $\vec{u}-\frac{3}{\|\vec{u}\|}\vec{a}$.

Comment: Where did you find this? Maybe it's defined somewhere in your book

Answer (score 1):

You are correct; there's no concept of dividing by a vector.

It may be a typo in the problem you're solving -- perhaps it should be $ \vec u - \frac3{\vec u\cdot \vec a}\cdot \vec a$ or $\vec u - \frac{3}{|\vec u|}\cdot\vec a $?

Or perhaps it is some idiosyncratic notation that you'll have to ask the person who gave you the problem about.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. You are right: it is undefined.

Perhaps that whover wrote it meant $\dfrac3{\left\lVert\vec u\right\rVert}$.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps
$\frac1{\vec{u}}
$
is a vector such that
$\frac1{\vec{u}}\times\vec{u}
=I 
$.

Comment: If by $I$ you mean an identity matrix and if by $\times$ you mean the product of a column vector by a row vector to produce a matrix, then there will be no such reciprocal because such a column $\times$ row matrix product always has rank $1$ or $0$.

Comment: I mean cross product.

Comment: So $I$ is supposed to be a vector?